# Trouble with hello world linux kernel module makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have this code for the hello world module :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello module\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bye module\n");
}
```

Makefile :

```
obj-m := hello.o
K := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
    make -C $(K) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I get this compile message from the makefile :

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build M=/home/neo/ker modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/neo/ker/hello.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/neo/ker/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/neo/ker/hello.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
```

this is the warning  that i don't understand:

```
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The warning seems to refer to a line in the makefile in '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64', which is not (necessarily) this makefile.

Comment: @Beta So what you recommend to do ? im a really big kernel noob

Comment: I recommend that you not worry about it. A warning about deprecated syntax is not a serious problem; if you want to pursue it, then look at that makefile. If you cannot see the cause of the warning, then you are probably not yet skilled enough at Make for the answer to be of much value to you. (But if you like you can show us the line.)